# HTTP "Content-Type" "application/octet-stream" is not supported in Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, firefox, audio, nginx

I was just deploying my very first Ruby on Rails application to Engine Yard, and now the media player does not work in Firefox.

So far I am only supporting Opera, Chrome and Safari. On the local test server the media player was working as well with Firefox. I am using the very basic HTML5 player.

```
<audio id="audio_<%=i%>" controls="controls" height="100" width="200" title="Variante <%= @ind_titel[i]%>">   
    <source src='/audio/mp3/<%=value%>.mp3' type="audio/mp3" />                             
    <source src='/audio/ogg/<%=value%>.ogg' type="audio/ogg" />                       
<embed height="100" width="100" src='/audio/mp3/<%=value%>.mp3' />
</audio>
```

Firebug gives me something like:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" "application/octet-stream" is not supported in Firefox
```

**Edit:**
I have changed now the /etc/nginx/mime.types on the Server and added the lines:

```
application/ogg ogg ogx;
audio/ogg oga;
```

But it still does not work...
According to this instruction: http://9elements.com/io/?p=306

I have tried to change as well the config/initializers/mime_types.rb
with the given lines but my local test server didnt even start with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but it sounds like your server is not reporting the proper mime types for your audio files. You could check by navigating to the audio file directly and checking the content type in the headers of Firebug's net tab. If that's the case apache (or whatever server you use) may have to be configured to report the proper mime type for .mp3 and .ogg files.